# Meaning of おつけして in 「4900円のところ、今日はなんともうーつおつけして、4900円」

Tags: words

> さあ、次の商品は、今アメリカで話題のパワーキャッチャーのご紹介です。運動不足で、お悩みのみなさまにお送りす驚きのパワーキャッチャ。使い方はとても簡単。体の気になるところにパワーキャッチャーをのせるだけで、ほら！このとおり。のせにくいところには、専用ベルトをこのようにつけて巻けば、どこにでも使えます。形は丸くて、体にぴったり。四角ぃ窓には、残り時間や運動量を表示します。この窓中央にあるから見やすいんです。また、窓の左右にはボタンがあります。この三角のボタンで強さと速さがかえられます。便利なパワーキャッチャ、いつもは4900円、4900円のところ、今日はなんともうーつ**おつけして**、4900円。ぜひ、今すぐお電話を！！

This is a made up ad (listening practice) for a パワーキャッチャー.

I wonder what おつけして means here. I believe this is:

> お + つける(連用形) + する which makes つける polite.

What does つける mean here though? Maybe an extra item follows with the パワーキャッチャー, but the price is still 4900円?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's the humble form of 付ける ("to attach").

This person is saying he will attach another "power catcher" as a bonus. Exactly the same product. This ("XYZ yen is the price for TWO!") is a [classic marketing method](https://www.tsuhan-marketing.com/blog/electricwave/infomercial_presentoffer) of home shopping shows at least in Japan. It's effectively the same as "buy one get one free".